# Unable to start android emulator on mac. Library not loaded libc++.1.dylib

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator Image - API 17, armeabi-v7a

`tools$ emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_17
dyld: Library not loaded: /tmp/darwin-x86_64-clang-3.5/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/madhav/Library/Android/sdk/tools/./emulator
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your .profile and .bashrc to see if DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is set there and if so try commenting out those lines. For me, the Muse SDK had put in a line with this that broke the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Joshua, you need to remove or comment the line added by other applications.

The last line of my `.bash_profile` after fix now is:

```
#export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/Muse"
```